# pgAdmin won't start (eternal loading)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

Once upon a time I had a Postgres database that worked with pgAdmin. I have a webservice running on a WildFly server that made connections to the DB and everything worked fine.

After a while(a few months) I have tried to open pgAdmin again and it stuck on the loading...

I remove postgres and pgAdmin using Revo Uninstall, then installed postgres 9.6 and opened pgAdmin and it stays in the loading screen forever.

Can anyone help me ? [Using postgres 9.6 with pgAdmin v1.3],

On Event Viewer I saw the following error in pgAdmin :

Faulting application name: pgAdmin4.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x580f31f6
Faulting module name: MSVCP120.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18438, time stamp: 0x57ae642e
Exception code: 0xc0000135
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecdd0
Faulting process id: 0x1de4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2a7d1566324ba
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe
Faulting module path: MSVCP120.dll
Report Id: 984dd9d8-13c4-11e7-832d-5ce0c535006f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: What is your OS, which version?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I am using windows 8

Comment: Have you seen the windows logs? I suspect that it must be something related with security permissions.

Comment: "Server started and accepting connections"

Comment: Not the postgresql logs, the application logs in windows computer management. Your problem seems to be with the pgAdmin which is just a client for postgresql server. So you need to see if there is any problem with it in windows logs.

Comment: I am looking to Event Viewer > Windows Logs . To logs with source in Postgres

Comment: Don't look for postgres, look for pgadmin. They are not the same.

Comment: In the event viewer I don't see anything from pgadmin or postgress under application logs.  I'm on Windows server 2012 r2 .  Killing the process doesn't help.  I don't have permissions to restart this host.

Comment: Don't use any version of pgAdmin prior to version 4.29.  Junk.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I needed to downgrade my Python: https://askubuntu.com/a/1461009/48214

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same issue on a Windows 7, 64bit machine, DBA told me to "upgrade" to pgAdmin 3 (latest build) and it works.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Windows 10 64bit. It's worth noting that restarting the computer allowed pgAdmin4 to load, but strangely the next time I restarted my computer pgAdmin 4 was stuck in the eternal loading state once again. pgAdmin3 seems to be more reliable.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround. Abrahim's answer has a proper solution.

Comment: At the time this was the only solution that allowed me to be productive so I proposed it, OP accepted it as best solution back then, pretty sure things have changed since than.

Comment: As mentioned before Abrahim's answer is the correct solution

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem and I resolved it following the steps on link
https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#12

> When I launch pgAdmin 4 v4.28 or later on Windows, the loading page
> never closes. Why? pgAdmin 4 v4.28 includes additional security
> features, one of which is intended to prevent security issues caused
> by Content Sniffing.
>
> Unfortunately some Windows systems are mis-configured such that this
> causes Javascripts used by pgAdmin to fail to load. Opening the
> developer tools on your browser will show an error similar to this:
>
> Refused to execute script from
> 'http://127.0.0.1:57313/static/vendor/require/require.min.js?ver=42800'
> because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
> MIME type checking is enabled.
>
> (index):39 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at
> (index):39 This will occur when the value of the registry key at
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js\Content Type is set to text/plain. **To resolve
> the issue, use the Registry Editor and reset the value of
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type to: text/javascript**
>
> Finally, restart the pgAdmin server.

Comment: This is still the right thing to do in Dec 2020.

Comment: Also, after changing registry, I had to kill `pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime` process by *Task Manager* and run pgAdmin again.

Comment: There is no Content Type folder under .js

Answer (score 19):

I just had this problem on macOS so I went to Terminal and typed `ps aux | grep -i pgadmin` and made a note of the process id (second column from the left).  Then I killed that process with `kill -s TERM <process id>`.  You can also use the simpler form with `killall pgAdmin4`.  Then I was able to start "pgAdmin 4" from the Applications directory.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  There are a few process that open outside of the browser when PGAdmin4 starts.  I'm betting you could also bookmark the web page that launches and just start from there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It solved the problem without downgrading.

Comment: killall pgadmin4 and rebooting it up fixed it for me

Comment: Hmm, `killall pgAdmin4` on Ubuntu says "pgAdmin4: no process found", so I guess my problem has a different cause. Thanks anyway.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I needed to downgrade my Python: https://askubuntu.com/a/1461009/48214

Answer (score 4):

as per Abrahim's suggestion, it worked fine for me in the environment. Windows 10, pgAdmin 4.28

"value of the registry key at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js\Content Type is set to text/plain. To resolve the issue, use the Registry Editor and reset the value of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js\Content Type to: text/javascript "

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Mac. I resolved it by:

1. Closing the instance of PgAdmin 3 AND PgAdmin4 (I had both open)
2. System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere
3. Reopen PgAdmin4

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue (on window server)
My solution is just open task manager and finds out pg_ctl then just end that task and reopen pgadmin again. It will work!in case it still doesn't work just try to terminate mysql.exe too.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the postgresql server was set to start manual and it was not running in services, i started the service and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Download pgAdmin from its website and install it separately from postgres.(Its works for me on Windows 10 - 64 Bit)

Answer (score 0):

Response from pgadmin-support mail group:

Please try one of the Mac/Windows test builds at https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/. 
I would strongly advise doing a complete uninstall before installing, to ensure no old, unused files are left behind.

Comment: I removed pgAdmin using revo uninstall pro, then installed this test build and it didn't work (same error as before).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to fix it by re-installing the latest Java JDK x64 8 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here [pgAdmin 4 v3.1 How can I use another browser? (Win 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637530/pgadmin-4-v3-1-how-can-i-use-another-browser-win-7)

My pgadmin4 stopped working in firefox but it works in chrome. Now i use this configuration to open pgadmin 4 using chrome. It is interesting that pgadmin4 now open in his own window.

I think this is the correct way to use pgadmin4.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Services and restart PostgreSQL Server.

[image: Restart Server]

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to come here while trying to troubleshoot similar issue on mac,  note that sometimes pgadmin setup done while installing postgres doesn't work.
Uninstall pgadmin - go to postgres installation directory, click uninstall - uninstall selected app - pgadmin. Once the uninstall is complete. Download a fresh pgadmin.
It worked for me.

Ref - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327474/pgadmin-4-v-7-1-not-loading-after-trying-everything

One other possible solution can be - [https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#:~:text=then%20restart%20pgAdmin.-,On%20macOS%2C%20I%20get%20an%20error%20like%3A%20%22pgAdmin%204%20is%20damaged%20and%20cannot%20be%20opened%22,-This%20has%20been](https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#:%7E:text=then%20restart%20pgAdmin.-,On%20macOS%2C%20I%20get%20an%20error%20like%3A%20%22pgAdmin%204%20is%20damaged%20and%20cannot%20be%20opened%22,-This%20has%20been)